# Two databases interpreting data differently

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is by far the weirdest thing I have come across in SQL Server:

DB 1: 
TableA
Id, FieldXYZ

TableB
Id, FieldXYZ

DB2:
TableA
ID, FieldXYZ

TableB
Id, FieldXYZ

```
Query 1 in DB1:
Select *, 'Unmapped' as Flag 
FROM TableA 
Where NOT EXISTS (Select * FROM TableB B JOIN TableA A ON ISNULL(B.XYZ,'')=ISNULL(A.XYZ,''))

Result:
Id , XYZ , Flag   
23         unmapped   ---- Field XYZ here is blank, not NULL, just blank


Query 1 in DB2:
    Select *, 'Unmapped' as Flag 
    FROM TableA 
    Where NOT EXISTS (Select * FROM TableB B JOIN Table A ON ISNULL(B.XYZ,'')=ISNULL(A.XYZ,''))

Result:
Id , XYZ , Flag   --- I don't get any results in the DB2 for the same data as DB1
```

If I modify my query in DB1 as follows, then I don't get anything as "unmapped":

```
Query 2 in DB1:
Select *, 'Unmapped' as Flag 
FROM TableA 
Where NOT EXISTS (Select * FROM TableB B JOIN TableA A ON ISNULL(B.XYZ,'')=ISNULL(A.XYZ,'') OR A.XYZ = ' ') -- there is a space here in A.XYZ = ' '
```

If run the following query in the two db, I get a record from each:

```
SELECT * FROM DB1.dbo.TableA where FieldXYZ = ' ' -- space within quotes

SELECT * FROM DB2.dbo.TableA where FieldXYZ = ' ' -- space within quotes
```

So what is happening with Query 1 in db1?

Comment: `JOIN ON` is syntactically incorrect, so I find it hard to believe that any of these queries are producing any results.

Comment: are there different fields "FieldXYZ" and "XYZ" ? you mention both in your example queries.

Comment: They are the same, I apologize for the typo. I was looking more of a conceptual answer to my issue here than actual code.

Comment: Shouldn't the subquery in your `WHERE NOT EXISTS` reference the `TableA` in the main query?  Since you are joining to a new `TableA` variable, I would expect your results to be misleading.

Comment: can you run the NOT EXISTS query "Select * FROM TableB B JOIN TableA A ON ISNULL(B.XYZ,'')=ISNULL(A.XYZ,'')" on both DB and check if you get same result ?

Comment: Comparsions of strings with trailing spaces have funky rules. Are they affected by collation? I don't know but I'd check the collations of the relevant columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all of the records from `TableA` that do not match `TableB` then your query is wrong.

You really want this:

```
SELECT TableA.*, 'Unmapped' as Flag 
FROM TableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB
ON ISNULL(TableA.XYZ,'') = ISNULL(TableB.XYZ,''))
WHERE TableB.ID IS NULL
```

Here's what your query is doing:

```
Select *, 'Unmapped' as Flag 
FROM TableA 
Where NOT EXISTS (
    Select *
    FROM TableB B
    JOIN TableA A
    ON ISNULL(B.XYZ,'')=ISNULL(A.XYZ,'')
)
```

1. Try to match `TableA` with `TableB` on the `XYZ` field.
2. If there are no matches for any of the records, then return ALL records from `TableA`.

Another option would be:

```
Select *, 'Unmapped' as Flag 
FROM TableA 
Where NOT EXISTS (
    Select *
    FROM TableB B
    WHERE ISNULL(B.XYZ,'') = ISNULL(TableA.XYZ,'')
)
```

Notice that the subquery references back to the `TableA` in the main query.

Answer (score 0):

as I mentioned in the Comment if you run only NOT EXISTS query in both DB you will see the same difference in result for those DB. So my point is issue is not in "NOT EXISTS" clause it is in the "ISNULL" condition used inside that query.

that's why we should not use the "ISNULL" function to check the NULL value of column instead use the "IS NULL" clause.

[Do not use ISNULL to find NULL values. Use IS NULL instead](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

if you change your query as follows you should be good and see the same result.

```
    Select * 
    FROM TableB B 
    JOIN Table A ON 
        (CASE WHEN B.XYZ IS NULL THEN '' ELSE B.XYZ END)
        =
        (CASE WHEN A.XYZ IS NULL THEN '' ELSE A.XYZ END)
```